# Использование Stream API

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, потоки-данных

```
for (String a : arr) {
    if (!a.equals("")) {
       dateValues.add(Integer.parseInt(a));
    }
}
```

Добрый день, можно ли как-то данный цикл сделать с помощью Stream API ( делаю для себя, просто интересно )

Понимаю, что задача достаточная тривиальная, но с функциональным программированием у меня пока слабовато...

Я вижу это примерно как-то так, но я пока не смог понять, как убрать - "" силами Stream API

`Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(a -> dateValues.add(Integer.parseInt(a)));`

**Либо, может быть кто-нибудь сможет подсказать :**

Входные данные :

`String date = "20/10/2020 - 20/09/2020"`

С помощью
`String[] arr = date.split("\\D+");`

Формируется массив, в котором остаются следующие данные :

```
arr[0] = ""
arr[1] = 20
arr[2] = 10
arr[3] = 2020
....
```

и так-далее.

ВОПРОС : откуда берется arr[0] = ""? И можно ли как-то убрать его с помощью регулярки?

Comment: Можно удалить все совпадения в начале строки, а потом разбивать на части: `String[] arr = date.replaceFirst("^\\D+", "").split("\\D+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> dateValues = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(a -> !a.isEmpty())
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Arrays.stream(arr).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).forEach(a -> dateValues.add(Integer.parseInt(a)));

собственно я так и решил примерно. Спасибо.

Comment: У Вас более изящно, т.к. не надо делать так

        List<Integer> dateValues = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @Васька стримы не должны менять состояние, а именно это вы и делаете в forEach.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо Вам большое!!! Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могу почитать, почему стримы не должны менять состояние? Я был бы Вам очень признателен. А еще было бы здорово, если бы Вы посоветовали статьи по данной тематике. (Кроме Шпаргалка Java программиста 4. Java Stream API с хабра , и аннимона?)

Comment: @Васька Ричард Уорбэртон - "Лямбда-выражения в Java 8"

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое? более понятное к вам

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "20/10/2020 - 20/09/2020";
    String[] arr = date.split("\\D+");
    List<Integer> dateValues = new ArrayList();
    Arrays.asList(arr)
        .stream().forEach(
            item -> {
              if (!item.equals("")) {
                dateValues.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
              }
            });
    System.out.println(dateValues);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем, спасибо. Немного подправил код

```
    private List<LocalDateTime> dateConvertation(String date) {

        String[] arr = date.split("\\D+");

        List<Integer> dateValues = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(dateValues.get(2), dateValues.get(1), dateValues.get(0), 0, 0);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(dateValues.get(5), dateValues.get(4), dateValues.get(3), 23, 59);
        List<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
        localDateTimeList.add(startDateTime);
        localDateTimeList.add(endDateTime);

        return localDateTimeList;
    }
```